# control returned type based function parameter in typescript

Tags: typescript

I want control output data type of function based on the input of function based on what I defined before.
I have some events, each of which has its own data type like below:

```
enum Event {
    Start = "start",
    UserJoin = "user_join",
    UserLeave = "user_leave",
}

interface Data {
    [Event.Start]: Session
    [Event.UserJoin]: User
    [Event.UserLeave]: { user_id: number }
}
```

I want to have a function that get the event and the output of this function is related Data:

```
type EventMap = {
    [Key in keyof Data]: { event: Key; data: Data[Key]}
};

type DataEventMap = EventMap[keyof EventMap]

const listenToEvent = (event: Event) => {
    return new Observable<DataEventMap>(observer => {
        const listerner = (data: DataEventMap) => observer.next(data)
        socket.on("get-data", listerner)
    })
}
```

Comment: Does [this approach](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/KYOwrgtgBAsgngUQG6gC5QN4CgpQMqoCGATugLxQBEAzkaZQDQ5QCq1wxAUgPYCWIUCpTDtiAfQBWfEI2ZsOAGWCEUgqiI5iANspSUsAXyxZUcAA7B8watV7cBFDAYDcJ85fnE1T11n6oOADNCAGNLABFCIkxmAG14ZDQAOgISVABdAC4rGzsQV1x4xBQQVCTPHn4s1lECqCLE0vLRJRVgaowNcV4AE2zwCAAjDhdDY1MLKEbUGEIzbziAaWA4KH4oAGsV7kCoSKIO4BLUbOW4ZygeqMJs-cJYs-TR0bdJu+nZ+YoPudituB2U2On3SvhC9loUC0vFooAAKtxpmoADxwqDAAAeARAPWosGKaAAfAAKZhHNDZOFYACU2R+ZlicPSsUoVyIlHSgkJMVwAHpeWsIGYdBA0FE8sxiMBUGBiAInFBCHjCCBzoYwRD0GzCGpobCQAjpsSEscUnRUNTnEA) work out for you?

Comment: @Behemoth
Thanks, that was very helpful. In my case, I am using a socket and I need to listen to the correct event, I made a change in your code and changed the output to observable, but there is a problem, can you fix this?  
[editedlistenToEvent](https://2cm.es/svJm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adopt your function `listenToEvent()` to accept a generic parameter `T` that `extends Event`. And add an explicit return type of `Observable<EventMap[T]["data"]>`. This way the correct value of a property of the `Data` interface will be inferred correctly.

Now there is only one problem left: `data.data` still has a union type which we cannot pass to `observer.next()`. This is a valid situation to use [Type Assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions).

```
enum Event {
  Start = "start",
  UserJoin = "user_join",
  UserLeave = "user_leave"
}

type Session = {};
type User = {};

interface Data {
  [Event.Start]: Session;
  [Event.UserJoin]: User;
  [Event.UserLeave]: {user_id: number};
}

type EventMap = {
  [Key in keyof Data]: {event: Key; data: Data[Key]};
};

type DataEventMap = EventMap[keyof EventMap];

const listenToEvent = <T extends Event>(
    event: T
  ): Observable<EventMap[T]["data"]> => {
    return new Observable(observer => {
        const listerner = (data: DataEventMap) => {
            if(data.event == event) observer.next(data.data as EventMap[T]["data"])
        }
        socket.on("get-data", listerner)
    })
};

const data = listenToEvent(MyEvent.Start);
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgeQEYGcCmUBuBDVAG0wBo4AzYQmbOAXwqghDgCIoAPAK3VYChQkWIjgBlCAGMA1phhlgEeo2Zt0kmTAB0CgLQTCwTADsY-PhIhH08NdNkAuMetkAeUdhzYAKhADCB4xgAUU8TdAA+OABeOAUACgBKPgETbHI8CUwxD28-AJMQwPREPjgytgBzWR0AEzwYPFZHOLqGxwARerxCkwBZPDAE6MicCGAavjpk4wBXFl6ATx74BFKxBuEY1ms8WFYSNYBVLCgAKTGjaLYZk4B9Lgv9o5OAGUw8TyvWG+xb4g-MPwpnwYAswFl3Oh0ApLjEEHQANwgsFZY60OGI5LAVJQdKZOCdBolMoAbUWy00og2MAAuo5IdDLEjSeTQlo0WcLnS4BzmXAyUs2ZoOW8AdyED8oLdxo4jHNUNhMcDQeC4Mt+mArqtSQBpTALWKXGQLCDkAldcWYNmOPULBFwVp4DpdEm2mlKpHI1WE7psjVXdUDEnG01qv0DGmeixWeAGazGHzLK4uLxwTAcGhGGrFVmBcJxNZlK2BRxeNYJRxoE74IiYFyBsAkrw0kmsR2sGmRKKRbXlKCyGZQS5GTAAdxQGA8BGIcQgk9w6J7hfKZWj1jgcZoQ-RcBaXWdDQbQ27xJXZ7KwHIe4ammLJmiMTvMCGc+r2E0I4z17wmkdcDwxQNk2LZtl0HZJOeZRTJBcC2BomiWHErBVDAtRgWQm7YCOUAQeUdBJJi5iWOuf4xJhRiJmycS5iYlLUgkCJAA)